# Just put calcium carbonate rocks in my condensate water pump or buy a whole condensate kit?

Tags: hvac, condensate

Can I just put some calcium carbonate rocks in my Beckett water pump (see photo of pump, below) to neutralize the HVAC condensate, or do I have to spring for a whole assembly, like this [image: condensate neutralization kit]

(The refills are less expensive than the whole assembly, and just putting some rocks in the pump basin is easier than installing a whole kit.)  If so, how often would I have to change or replace the rocks?[image: Beckett water pump]

Comment: Do you have a local ordinance requiring the treatment of the condensate? I would not waste the time and or $ trying to adjust the ph.

Comment: @EdBeal  Are you saying there is no practical need to neutralize the condensate?  Various websites say the condensate is corrosive, for example: https://welterheating.com/condensate-neutralizer/

Comment: It depends, distilled water is it bad? Well condensate is similar. Just saying.

Comment: @EdBeal. The website says, "condensate is acidic, it can cause damage to your water pipes, causing them to corrode prematurely. Acidic condensate can also cause serious damage to local sewers, pipes, septic systems, and water treatment facilities."  That sounds serious.  But you are saying it is just distilled water.  Do you know if and why the condensate is acidic?

Comment: Go ahead and spend $ if you want the minute the small amount of condensate mixed with grey water it is no longer acidic. Water that had been distilled usually becomes acidic after sitting but a properly drained system you have distilled water instead of water heater to produce steam and the steam condensed to make distilled water ac systems condense the moisture out of the air (the same as a glass of ice water sweats) do you realize your furnace is made out of sheet metal much thinner than a pipe, if it were really a problem the water would eat through the pan in months as it is so thin.

Comment: @EdBeal  One gov website says, "Condensate from condensing boilers contains carbonic acid ...has a pH of 3."  Is that level of acidity likely to harm a soil pipe or copper tubing used for the outflow?  (See: https://www.energy.gov.au/sites/default/files/hvac-factsheet-boiler-efficiency.pdf)

Comment: Did you look at the thin sheet metal pan that contains the collected water, yes sheet metal. But go ahead and do whatever , note that cheap condensate pump that has all plastic parts will be the first part of your system to fail. Adding water tape so you know when it fails would money better spent.

Comment: FWIW: the drip pan in my gas furnace is made of plastic, presumably to resist the acidic condensation. And the copper pipe that was installed instead of the PVC that should have been used, has been eaten all the way through, requiring replacement (with PVC of course). It is clear that the condensate is not just distilled water. I don't know the chemistry...I would've guess nitric acid rather than carbonic acid, but either way, you'll want to neutralize if it's going to go somewhere that acid shouldn't be.

Comment: @PeterDuniho  Hoe long did it take for the copper pipe to get eaten?  Did the water eat the pipe along its whole length, or in one place?

Comment: @Yehuda: it corroded over a span of several years, maybe ten. It was a progressive process, helped by lax home maintenance tactics, such as using high-strength packing tape as a temporary way to seal up the gap while waiting to get around to replacing the copper with PVC. That occurred a couple of times, as the corrosion worked its way down the pipe; it seems the acidity is neutralized as it reacts with the copper, so less corrosion occurs further down the pipe. Ultimately the house was sold to a builder and torn down to make way for new construction, before said PVC replacement ever happened.

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't clarify why you'd rather drop stones in the pump than to replace the stones in a filter cartridge. Regardless, the reaction between acidic water and caustic stone is going to take place anywhere they meet. I've seen limestone dropped into acidic rain water barrels to raise the pH for watering gardens.

The ordinance in my area is that the HVAC condensate must be discharged outside the building, or the condensate must be neutralized before it goes into waste water plumbing. My HVAC condensate is gravity fed to a side yard, with no special stones. The grass there grows like normal so I've never given it a second thought.

Back to your question. If the filter pump is a code requirement, i.e., the water must be treated before it can be discharged into your waste water system, I wouldn't mess with the pump filter system. It's not worth a fine or the liability.

Yehuda_NYC, the cartridges look like the end-caps spin off. They might be designed to be refilled. Putting stones in the cartridges shouldn't cost any more than dropping stones in the pump. The least expensive route is to re-route the distillate tubing to drain outside - if it is in compliance with your local ordinances.

Comment: I just want to avoid the time and expense of buying and installing the neutralization cartridge kit.

Comment: This goes back to is it required? I have never installed a neutralizer , most plumbing since the 70’s is plastic and it won’t affect plastic. When I install a system I drain to whatever is easy. Many times a hole through the wall others into the drain system. The condensate off the fire box or condensing coils is safe to be touched it is not like a drain cleaner more like rain water in some cases. The places that push treatment SELL the treatment systems.